# Twig: Extend template !only! on condition? Or dynamicly extend on PHP-side

Tags: symfony, twig

I've got a twig template:

```
{% extends base %}
{% block content %}
   some content
{% endblock %}
```

Is there any way to render it without "extending" any template?
If i leave the "base" unset, an error appears.

Something like

```
{% if base is defined %}
   {% extends base %}
{% endif %}
```

does not work, as far as i know.

Or another option might be, if there is a way to dynamicly define a parent on the php side, like u can do in Smarty:

```
$smarty->display('extends:layout.tpl|myproject.tpl|mypage.tpl');
```

Thx!

Comment: You could manually render a specific block if that is a solution?

Comment: Yeah, the only way i can imagine to solve this now, is render a template "manually" without extends and then just paste it as a variable into the base template. I will have to use this option if there is no other way.

Comment: Btw, this is pretty bad solution, ur "child" templates losing all the power of template inheritance when generated content passed as variable into base. I'm sure there is some more drawbacks on this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally set template:

```
{% extends base is defined ? 'main.html.twig' : 'empty.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: Thx, but this solution also has a drawback. I need to add all the blocks that must be generated in child templates to the empty template. Well, have no other choise probably.